# Python: Trouble making separate plots using plot_drawdown_underwater from pyfolio and get_data_yahoo from pandas-datareader to plot stock drawdown

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I have this code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pyfolio as pf

myStartDate = "2019-1-1"   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myEndDate = "2020-11-11"   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myTickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT"]

myData = pdr.get_data_yahoo(myTickers, myStartDate, myEndDate)

myDailyAdjustedClose = myData[['Adj Close']]
returns = myDailyAdjustedClose.pct_change()

pf.plot_drawdown_underwater(returns)
```

The problem is that both Apple and Microsoft are plotted on the same plot. Instead, I want 2 separate plots.

Instead of "pf.plot_drawdown_underwater(returns)" I also tried:

```
for x in range(returns.shape[1]):
    columnData = returns.iloc[:, x]
    pf.plot_drawdown_underwater(columnData)
```

But I still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pyfolio as pf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myStartDate = "2019-1-1"   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myEndDate = "2020-11-11"   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myTickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT"]

myData = pdr.get_data_yahoo(myTickers, myStartDate, myEndDate)

myDailyAdjustedClose = myData[['Adj Close']]
returns = myDailyAdjustedClose.pct_change()

returnsColumnCount = returns.shape[1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(returnsColumnCount, 1, figsize=(10, 10))
fig.tight_layout(pad=5)

for x in range(returnsColumnCount):
    columnData = returns.iloc[:, x]
    pf.plot_drawdown_underwater(columnData, ax=ax[x])

plt.show();
```